# iOS / Obj-C: Removing the padding from UIButton titles

Tags: ios, uibutton, uilabel, padding, uiedgeinsets

I am trying to create a very thin `UIButton` with size = `CGSizeMake(75, 23)` to fit a customized background image exactly.  And I would like the button to have a title.

After I call `setTitle:forState:` the button is resized to account for padding around the title, screwing up the background image (i.e. causing it to tile very unseemly).  I have set the title font to quite a small size in the `UILabel` subview, so it's not the font that's causing the problem but the padding.  Thus I would like to remove this padding.  The default values of the `contentEdgeInsets`, `imageEdgeInsets` and `titleEdgeInsets` properties of `UIButton` are all `UIEdgeInsetsZero`, so I presume the padding is somewhere in the `UILabel` subview.  If so, I think I can eliminate it by subclassing `UILabel` and overriding [`textRectForBounds:limitedToNumberOfLines:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UILabel_Class/Reference/UILabel.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UILabel/textRectForBounds%3alimitedToNumberOfLines%3a) but I'm not sure (and I'd be happy to hear from someone who has tried this).  In any event, I'm looking for an easier way out.

I've searched and searched and haven't found anything.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you try setting the frame of the button after you set the title?

Comment: Are you using PNG for the buttons? Try adding the label onto the PNG file itself, then you can avoid any padding that the label causes. This does of course mean you loose the ability to change the button labels on the fly.

Comment: @lnafziger yep, tried that to no avail, unfortunately.

Comment: @Jeff Kranenburg, yep, I'm using PNG, but I do need to change the title dynamically, so hardwiring it in is not an option, unfortunately.  What I'm considering doing is enlarging the PNG file's canvas with transparent pixels so as to cover the padding.  This will mean, of course, that the button will include the transparent pixels, which is not desirable since those pixels will generate touch events.

Comment: @lnafziger I guess I should also mention that I've tried setting the frame of the `UILabel` subview after I've set the title, but again to no avail.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what to do!

Answer (score 0):

That would work.

I have recommended this tool before but it's a miracle worker:-)

[OBShapedButton](https://github.com/ole/OBShapedButton)

It will take care of your transparency problem 
That should solve your issue:-)

Comment: Thanks @JeffKranenburg, `OBShapedButton` seems like a good solution and it does solve the transparency issue, but I will hold off on implementing it unless I cannot find another solution, since there will likely be some performance loss (there will be over twenty instances of this button on a view at any given time).

Comment: I see what you mean - I have an app and it uses 8 instances of it on the start screen. Haven't noticed anything. But I am guessing there has to be some give and take. Even if you implement it now until you find a better solution.